# How to populate one pickist value based on another picklist value in one vf page

Tags: picklist

I have a visualforce page and two picklist fields.
Field 1 contains values as A,B and C.
Field 2 contains values as X and Y.

I want to have both X and Y in field 2 when option A/B is selected in field 1 and populate Y when option C is selected.

I tried doing this using field dependency.But Y is not getting populated.It always populates the default value.

Your help is aprreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `<apex:actionSupport` as below.  The second `<apex:selectList` is populated based on the value selected in First `<apex:selectList`. Hope this helps.

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page controller="picklistController">
    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:selectList id="selected_list" value="{!dropdown1}" required="false" size="1">
            <apex:selectOption itemvalue="None" itemLabel="--None--"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemvalue="A" itemLabel="A"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemvalue="B" itemLabel="B"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemvalue="C" itemLabel="C"/>
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="form" action="{!updateDropdown}"/>
        </apex:selectList>
        <apex:selectList id="dropdown2"  required="false" size="1">
            <apex:selectOption itemvalue="None" itemLabel="--None--"/>
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}" />
        </apex:selectList>        
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller**

```
public class picklistController {
    public String dropdown1{get; set;}
    public List<SelectOption> options;
    public void updateDropdown() {
        if(dropdown1 == 'A' || dropdown1 == 'B' ){
            options = new List<SelectOption>();
            options.add(new SelectOption('X','X'));
            options.add(new SelectOption('Y','Y'));
        }else if(dropdown1 == 'C'){
            options = new List<SelectOption>();
            options.add(new SelectOption('Y','Y'));
        }    
    }
    public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
        return options;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have done it using selectList for the dependent pickList populated with a dynamic apex.

**Visual force page**

```
<apex:page standardController="MyCustomObject__c" extensions="PickListExtension">
<apex:form title="Title book">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Title">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}"  value="Save"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
            <apex:selectList multiselect="false" value="{!MyCustomObject__c.Field1__c}" size="1">
                  <apex:selectOptions value="{!Field1Items}"/>
                  <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="depfield"/>
            </apex:selectList>
            <apex:outputPanel id="depfield">
                <apex:selectList value="{!MyCustomObject__c.DepField__c}" size="1">
                  <apex:selectOptions value="{!DepItems}" />
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:outputPanel>

        </apex:pageBlockSection>

  </apex:pageBlock>
```

**Controller**

```
public class PickListExtension{
ApexPages.StandardController stdCont;
MyCustomObject__c myObject;


//Map Dependency. 
//I would like to know how to build this dynamically
Map<String, Set<String>> dependencyMap=new Map<String, Set<String>>();

public PickListExtension (ApexPages.StandardController stdCont){
    this.stdCont=stdCont;
    this.myObject=(MyCustomObject__c)stdCont.getRecord();

    //Pupulating dependency map
    //It would be interesting if this could be done dynamically

    Set<String> depItems1=new Set<String>();
    depItems1.add('X');
    depItems1.add('Y');
    dependencyMap.put('A', depItems1);
    dependencyMap.put('B', depItems1);

    Set<String> depItems2=new Set<String>();
    depItems2.add('Y');
    dependencyMap.put('C', depItems2);


}

public List<SelectOption> getField1Items(){
    List<SelectOption> options=new List<SelectOption>();
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult field1=MycustomObject__c.Field1__c.getDescribe();
    List<PickListEntry> pickVals=field1.getPickListValues();
    for(PickListEntry pickVal: pickVals){
        options.add(new SelectOption(pickVal.getLabel(), pickVal.getValue()));
    }
    return options;
}

public List<SelectOption> getDepItems(){
    List<SelectOption> options=new List<SelectOption>();
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult field1=Mycustomobject__c.DepField__c.getDescribe();
    List<PickListEntry> pickVals=field1.getPickListValues();
    Set<String> AcceptableValues=dependencyMap.get(book.Field1__c);
    for(PickListEntry pickVal: pickVals){
        if(AcceptableValues ==NULL  || AcceptableValues.contains(pickVal.getValue())){
            options.add(new SelectOption(pickVal.getLabel(), pickVal.getValue()));
        }
    }
    return options;
}  
}
```

But it remain one problem: How to apply the the depency dynamicly on the dependent pickList to take the value of the first pickList into consideration

Comment: It is possible to load controlling field value of a pickListValue using Metadata API ([PickList Value MetaData API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_picklist.htm#kanchor122).  This link explain how to call Metadata API from Apex code [How to call MetaData API from apew](http://andyinthecloud.com/2013/10/27/introduction-to-calling-the-metadata-api-from-apex/).